# ReactJS useEffect not firing on a variable and lint complains about missing dependencies in a different hook

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have an array of searches called "searchList". When I put something in search, I want to push that on the "searchList". For that I create a local variable searches and save the current state of searchList into it, then push the latest search into it and setSearchList with the new updated array (this doesn't work see second part of the question).

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState(false);
const [searchList, setSearchList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    let searches = searchList;
    searches.push(search);
    setSearchList(searches);
    console.log(searches);
}, [search]); //when search is changed, update searchList
```

However here I get the warning of missing dependencies:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'searchList'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Why is that? I am not accessing it directly in the useEffect, but use the useState hook for that thus this shouldn't be triggered?

The same happens when I use any variable there.

Just for testing I added "somethingelse" there and I get the warning about "somethingelse" and "searchList" not in dependencies but I am only accessing "somethingelse" reading not doing anything else with it, why does it need to be a dependency?

```
const [searchList, setSearchList] = useState([]);
const [somethingelse, setSomethingelse] = useState('doesn't matter');

useEffect(() => {
    let searches = searchList;
    let something = somethingelse;

    searches.push(search);
    setSearchList(searches);
    console.log(searches);
}, [search]); //when search is changed, update searchList
```

Additionally a "searchList" useEffect is never called despite it getting filled:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("searchList", searchList);
}, [searchList]);
```

When I just put search into the list using "setSearchList(search)", this useEffect fires and gives me the latest search that was just put into searchList but when I put my temporal variable in there, it doesn't.

The console.log on the temporal variable "searches" in the other useEffect it returns a growing list of search entries, so searchList is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, when you say `let searches = searchList`, the `searches` variable now points to the same object in memory that `searchList` points to. That means when you `push` to `searches`, you're pushing to `searchList` (same object). To avoid this, make `searches` a shallow copy of `searchList` using something like the spread operator.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let searches = [...searchList];
    let something = somethingelse;
    searches.push(search);
    setSearchList(searches);
}, [search]);
```

A potentially more concise way to represent this could be by using a function in `setSearchList`, which additionally helps you avoid the dependency array warning you're getting.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let something = somethingelse;
    setSearchList(searchList => [...searchList, search]);
}, [search]);
```

Comment: "the searches variable now points to the same object in memory" Ok I am not a js programmer but I thought, "variable = other_variable" copies the contents of "other_variable" into the memory location of "variable"? Is javascript different here?

Comment: @Supertyp this does trip a lot of people up, but it's super important to understand in JS app development. Check out [this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-pine-fn22q) that shows object assignment clearly points to the same object in memory.

Comment: codesandbox never worked for me because it messes with some plugins (cookie security rule violation on the site), but I trust you. I am just puzzled, that js handles variables like this.

Comment: @Supertyp it seems bad until you start taking advantage of holding references to objects to accomplish tasks that might otherwise be harder

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't declare a state variable named "search". Try something like so.

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState(null);
```

Other approach could be also tested:

```
useEffect(() => {
...
}, []);// it will fire whatever variable change in your scope.
```

Comment: I did. Just didn't come with the paste. I updated question